# Accidentally deleted boot partition. System not booting up

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

This is how my partitions are.

```
sda1=512MiB
sda2=694GiB
sda3=3.89GiB(linux-swap)
```

I have tried so many things but nothing works out. I tried boot-repair. I changed flags and now I don't know which are the default flags of partitions. sda1 is empty now.

Comment: Before starting lots of fixes best to post link to summary report. If new install, then a re-install may be easiest. But often full  reinstall of just grub can fix an otherwise working install, using Boot-Repair's advanced mode. But best to review details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Read the documentation on testdisk.  If you haven't messed with the drive too much, you might be able to restore the partition and regain the data that was in it (You'll need a live boot USB/Disk). [Click here for a how-to](https://www.maketecheasier.com/recover-data-and-partitions-for-free-with-testdisk/)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you seem to have a mixed-up mess.

Since you "tried so many things" but didn't provide details, we can only guess at your skill level.

Your easiest solution is to backup and reinstall:

- Create a LiveUSB.
- Boot using the Live USB.
- Mount your hard drive. Backup your data to some other media.
- Reinstall Ubuntu using the LiveUSB.

There are many more complex solutions, including several methods of investigation and repair. The AskUbuntu format is oriented toward single questions, not the extended mentoring you need to learn those repair methods.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reinstall the boot partition basically by booting from a Ubuntu live USB, continue with the installation how you usually would and when you get to **installation type** select **something else** and click on continue. Select sda1 as drive for boot partition and continue with the rest of the installation.

Comment: `sda1` could be a `/boot`-partition, I don't see an evidence that `sda1` is EFI-partition, not enough details provided!

Comment: @mook765 The only clue that it **might** be an EFI partition is the UEFI tag in the original post, although I would agree the details are incomplete.

Comment: @ElderGeek Good point, if it was really the ESP, then there is no need to reinstall Ubuntu, just need to recreate ESP and reinstall Grub.